# How do I prefetch all objects in a database with Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

I need to migrate a large amount of data from another database, and it's running very slowly because I have to constantly check if the object already exists so I don't have duplicates. Is it possible to have a queryset which prefetches all objects? Kind of like `Asset.objects.prefetch_all()`. I don't think I can use `prefetch_related` for this since it only prefetches related objects.

Comment: You can use [`Prefetch` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) with `queryset=Foo.objects.all()`.

Comment: But that's then used to control `prefetch_related`. Can you use `Prefetch` without `prefetch_related`? All the documentation passes it into `prefetch_related`.

Comment: `Prefetch` and `prefetch_related` are only used for related objects, what you are asking makes no sense. `Prefetch` without `prefetch_related` is just a `QuerySet`

Comment: @IainShelvington I understand this, I'm not trying to use `prefetch_related`. What I'm trying to do is have the ORM prefetch all objects of type `Foo`. Yes, the result will be a queryset.

Comment: `Foo.objects.all()` is a queryset of all objects of type `Foo`

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, but that queryset is lazily loaded, which means there will be a round trip to the database for each lookup, which will be very slow. I want that exact queryset, but with all the objects prefetched from the database.

Comment: Once the queryset is evaluated it will contain every Foo object in the entire database. The only thing that is lazy about it is that it is not evaluated until you iterate over it

Comment: @IainShelvington So you're saying that if I do `Foo.objects.all().first()` it will load every single `Foo` object from the database? I don't think that's the case. But that's exactly the behavior that I need right now.

Comment: No, `first()` will select just one row from the database `Foo.objects.all()` will select all objects